# Using Pysparks rdd.parallelize().map() on functions of self-implemented objects/classes

Tags: python, class, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have objects I want to do calculations on in parallel, thus I thought I can resort to pyspark.

Consider this example, a class whose objects do have a number `i`, that can be squared wiht `square()`:

```py
class MyMathObject():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def square(self):
        return self.i ** 2


print(MyMathObject(3).square()) # Test one instance with regular python - works
```

Aditionally, I set up pyspark (in a jupyter notebook), and now I want to calculate the squares from 0 to 4 in parallel on my objects:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]")

rdd = sc.parallelize([MyMathObject(i) for i in range(5)])
rdd.map(lambda obj: obj.square()).collect() # This fails
```

This does not work - it results in a very long and for me mostly unhelpful error message.
The only line I find somewhat interesting is:

*AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyMathObject' on <module 'pyspark.daemon' from '/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py'>*

So, it seems to be something related with how the attribute `square()` is called, or so. I copy the full message at the end.

Pyspark itself seems to work; for example executing a the following on a plain python list returns the squared numbers as expected.

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([i for i in range(5)])
rdd.map(lambda i: i**2).collect()
```

Thus, there seems to be something flawed with the way I create or operate on my objects, but I can not track down the mistake.

The complete error message:

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 rdd = sc.parallelize([MyMathObject(i) for i in range(5)])
> ----> 2 rdd.map(lambda obj: obj.square()).collect()
>
> /opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
> 887         """
> 888         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
> --> 889             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
> 890         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
> 891
>
> /opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in **call**(self, *args)
> 1302
> 1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> -> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
> 1306
>
> /opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
> 325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> --> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, 192.168.2.108, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
> process()
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 597, in process
> serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 271, in dump_stream
> vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 147, in load_stream
> yield self._read_with_length(stream)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
> return self.loads(obj)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 458, in loads
> return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyMathObject' on <module 'pyspark.daemon' from '/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py'>
>
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2154)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>
> Driver stacktrace:
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2135)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2154)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2179)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
> process()
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 597, in process
> serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 271, in dump_stream
> vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 147, in load_stream
> yield self._read_with_length(stream)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
> return self.loads(obj)
> File "/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 458, in loads
> return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyMathObject' on <module 'pyspark.daemon' from '/opt/apache-spark-3/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py'>
>
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
> at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
> at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
> at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2154)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
> at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> ... 1 more

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like your mistake, but a way around this is to put the module in a separate Python file and import it:

e.g. Open a file `mymodule.py` with

```
class MyMathObject():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def square(self):
        return self.i ** 2
```

And in your main script, you can do

```
from mymodule import MyMathObject

rdd = sc.parallelize([MyMathObject(i) for i in range(5)])
rdd.map(lambda obj: obj.square()).collect()
```

which should give [0, 1, 4, 9, 16].

Comment: Okay - outsourcing the class to its own file/to a module works. 
If it's not a mistake on my end, maybe it's worth submitting a git issue, or so...